# Show hyphen in group by column

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am writing a sql query as

```
SELECT                      
    pj.PROJECT_ID,                      
    SUM(hr.HOURS) as totalhours,                      
    hr.week,    
    hr.week as YEAR_Week,    
    max(rl.IHC_OR_EXTERNAL) as IHC,      
    max(rl.COMPANY_NAME) as companyName,       
    max(pj.PROJECT_SEGMENT) as segment,             
    max(hr.YEAR) as year,                      
    max(pj.PROJECT_STATUS) as PROJECT_STATUS,                      
    max(hr.RESOURCE_ID) as resourceId,                      
    max(hr.HOUR_TYPE) as hourType                    
FROM                      
    HOURS hr
    join PROJECT pj on hr.PROJECT_ID=pj.PROJECT_ID             
    join RESOURCE_LIST rl on hr.RESOURCE_ID=rl.RESOURCE_ID            
GROUP BY
    pj.PROJECT_ID,
    hr.WEEK
```

is it possible to show group by as with hyphen in between.

I am showing a chart on basis of this .In group by data like 201401, 201402 and so on. this is yearweek. I want to display year-week. Is this possible.

in select query, I can as

```
   regexp_replace(week, '(\d{4})(\d{2})', '\1-\2') as new_week
```

But how can i display in group by...?

Comment: Just put the same expression in the group by? E.g. `group by ...., regexp_replace(week, ...);`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by displaying something in a GROUP BY clause. What isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change anything in the GROUP BY clause, as adding the hyphen can be applied after grouping.

```
with demo (week, total) as
     ( select '201701', 1 from dual union all
       select '201701', 1 from dual union all
       select '201701', 1 from dual union all
       select '201702', 1 from dual union all
       select '201702', 1 from dual )
select regexp_replace(week, '(\d{4})(\d{2})', '\1-\2') as new_week
     , sum(total)
from   demo
group by week;

NEW_WEEK     SUM(TOTAL)
------------ ----------
2017-01               3
2017-02               2
```